# search database with php (new to php)

Tags: php, mysql

I am brand new to php and I am trying to teach myself to code. I am hoping that someone here can help a newb out. I have a database with 300 client records in it. I am using the following code to access the database. It works great but I am having two issues that I cannot seem to fix.

1) not all clients have a middle name listed and when the middle name field is blank it adds a

2) all 300 client records display at once. Is there a way I can set it to display only 1 to a max of 10 records at a time and use next previous buttons?

additionally, is there a way to search the database? for example a box, and I enter john in it and click search and it returns all records with John? If there is a video or walkthrough that is detailed enough I can figure it out if no one is able to provide me with the code.

Thank you in advance for the help.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
if (!$con) {
die("can not connect: " . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db ("new_concepts" ,$con);


if(isset($_POST['update'])){
$UpdateQuery = "UPDATE clients SET ClientID='$_POST[ClientID]', FirstName='$_POST[FirstName]', MiddleName='$_POST[MiddleName]', LastName='$_POST[LastName]', Diagnosis='$_POST[Diagnosis]', Gender='$_POST[Gender]', LevelCare='$_POST[LevelCare]', Counselor='$_POST[Counselor]' WHERE ClientID='$_POST[hidden]'";
mysql_query($UpdateQuery, $con);
};

if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
$DeleteQuery = "DELETE FROM clients WHERE ClientID='$_POST[hidden]'";          
mysql_query($DeleteQuery, $con);
};

if(isset($_POST['add'])){
$AddQuery = "INSERT INTO clients (ClientID, FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, Diagnosis, Gender, LevelCare, Counselor) VALUES ('$_POST[uclientid]','$_POST[ufirstname]','$_POST[umiddlename]','$_POST[ulastname]','$_POST[udiagnosis]','$_POST[ugender]','$_POST[ulevelcare]','$_POST[ucounselor]')";         
mysql_query($AddQuery, $con);
};



$sql = "SELECT * FROM clients";
$myData = mysql_query($sql,$con);
echo "<table border=1>
<tr>
<th>First Name</th>
<th>Middle Name</th>
<th>Last Name</th>
<th>Client ID</th>
<th>Diagnosis</th>
<th>Gender</th>
<th>Level of Care</th>
<th>Counselor</th>
</tr>";
while($record = mysql_fetch_array($myData)){
echo "<form action=mydata5.php method=post>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=FirstName value=" . $record['FirstName'] . " </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=MiddleName value=" . $record['MiddleName'] . " </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=LastName value=" . $record['LastName'] . " </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=ClientID value=" . $record['ClientID'] . " </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=Diagnosis value=" . $record['Diagnosis'] . " </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=Gender value=" . $record['Gender'] . " </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=LevelCare value=" . $record['LevelCare'] . " </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=Counselor value=" . $record['Counselor'] . " </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=hidden name=hidden value=" . $record['ClientID'] . " </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=submit name=update value=update" . " </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=submit name=delete value=delete" . " </td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</form>";
}
echo "<form action=mydata5.php method=post>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><input type=text name=ufirstname></td>";
echo "<td><input type=text name=umiddlename></td>";
echo "<td><input type=text name=ulastname></td>";
echo "<td><input type=text name=uclientid></td>";
echo "<td><input type=text name=udiagnosis></td>";
echo "<td><input type=text name=ugender></td>";
echo "<td><input type=text name=ulevelcare></td>";
echo "<td><input type=text name=ucounselor></td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=submit name=add value=add" . " </td>";
echo "</form>";
echo "</table>";
mysql_close($con);

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Ok I changed the page to sqli but now when I try to add a record nothing happens and I cannot find the error, I had it working until I started adding more fields then first/last names. I think I have narrowed the error to

```
 if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT clients (FirstName, MiddleName, LastName) VALUES (?,?, ?)"))
                {
                    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $FirstName, $MiddleName, $LastName);
                    $stmt->execute();
                    $stmt->close();
                }
```

But I have no idea how to fix it. I found the error!!! Ive only been learning php and MySQL for a week. I still have a lot to learn...

```
<?php
    /*
        Allows the user to both create new records and edit existing records
    */

    // connect to the database
    include("connect-db.php");

    // creates the new/edit record form
    // since this form is used multiple times in this file, I have made it a function that is easily reusable
    function renderForm($first = '', $middle = '', $last = '', $ClientID = '', $error = '', $ID = '')
    { ?>
        <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
        <html>
            <head>  
                <title>
                    <?php if ($ID != '') { echo "Edit Record"; } else { echo "New Record"; } ?>
                </title>
                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
            </head>
            <body>
                <h1><?php if ($ID != '') { echo "Edit Record"; } else { echo "New Record"; } ?></h1>
                <?php if ($error != '') {
                    echo "<div style='padding:4px; border:1px solid red; color:red'>" . $error
                        . "</div>";
                } ?>

                <form action="" method="post">
                <div>
                    <?php if ($ID != '') { ?>
                        <input type="hidden" name="ID" value="<?php echo $ID; ?>" />
                        <p>ID: <?php echo $ID; ?></p>
                    <?php } ?>

                    <strong>First Name: *</strong> <input type="text" name="FirstName"
                        value="<?php echo $first; ?>"/><br/>
                        <strong>Middle Name: *</strong> <input type="text" name="MiddleName"
                        value="<?php echo $middle; ?>"/>
                    <strong>Last Name: *</strong> <input type="text" name="LastName"
                        value="<?php echo $last; ?>"/>
                        <strong>Client ID: *</strong> <input type="text" name="ClientID"
                        value="<?php echo $ClientID; ?>"/>
                        <strong>Diagnosis: *</strong> <input type="text" name="Diagnosis"
                        value="<?php echo $last; ?>"/>
                        <strong>Gender: *</strong> <input type="text" name="Gender"
                        value="<?php echo $last; ?>"/>
                        <strong>Counselor: *</strong> <input type="text" name="Counselor"
                        value="<?php echo $last; ?>"/>
                    <p>* required</p>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
                </div>
                </form>
            </body>
        </html>

    <?php }



        /*

           EDIT RECORD

        */
    // if the 'ID' variable is set in the URL, we know that we need to edit a record
    if (isset($_GET['ID']))
    {
        // if the form's submit button is clicked, we need to process the form
        if (isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
            // make sure the 'ID' in the URL is valid
            if (is_numeric($_POST['ID']))
            {
                // get variables from the URL/form
                $ID = $_POST['ID'];
                $FirstName = htmlentities($_POST['FirstName'], ENT_QUOTES);
                $MiddleName = htmlentities($_POST['MiddleName'], ENT_QUOTES);
                $LastName = htmlentities($_POST['LastName'], ENT_QUOTES);
                $ClientID = htmlentities($_POST['ClientID'], ENT_QUOTES);

                // check that FirstName and LastName are both not empty
                if ($FirstName == '' || $MiddleName == '' || $LastName == '' || $ClientID == '')
                {
                    // if they are empty, show an error message and display the form
                    $error = 'ERROR: Please fill in all required fields!';
                    renderForm($FirstName, $MiddleName, $LastName, $ClientID, $error, $ID);
                }
                else
                {
                    // if everything is fine, update the record in the database
                    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE clients SET FirstName = ?, MiddleName = ?, LastName = ?, ClientID = ?
                        WHERE ID=?"))
                    {
                        $stmt->bind_param("ssi", $FirstName, $MiddleName, $LastName, $ClientID, $ID);
                        $stmt->execute();
                        $stmt->close();
                    }
                    // show an error message if the query has an error
                    else
                    {
                        echo "ERROR: could not prepare SQL statement.";
                    }

                    // redirect the user once the form is updated
                    header("Location: view.php");
                }
            }
            // if the 'ID' variable is not valid, show an error message
            else
            {
                echo "Error!";
            }
        }
        // if the form hasn't been submitted yet, get the info from the database and show the form
        else
        {
            // make sure the 'ID' value is valid
            if (is_numeric($_GET['ID']) && $_GET['ID'] > 0)
            {
                // get 'ID' from URL
                $ID = $_GET['ID'];

                // get the recod from the database
                if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM clients WHERE ID=?"))
                {
                    $stmt->bind_param("i", $ID);
                    $stmt->execute();

                    $stmt->bind_result($ID, $FirstName, $MiddleName, $LastName, $ClientID);
                    $stmt->fetch();

                    // show the form
                    renderForm($FirstName, $MiddleName, $LastName, $ClientID, NULL, $ID);

                    $stmt->close();
                }
                // show an error if the query has an error
                else
                {
                    echo "Error: could not prepare SQL statement";
                }
            }
            // if the 'ID' value is not valid, redirect the user back to the view.php page
            else
            {
                header("Location: view.php");
            }
        }
    }



        /*

           NEW RECORD

        */
    // if the 'ID' variable is not set in the URL, we must be creating a new record
    else
    {
        // if the form's submit button is clicked, we need to process the form
        if (isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
            // get the form data
            $FirstName = htmlentities($_POST['FirstName'], ENT_QUOTES);
            $MiddleName = htmlentities($_POST['MiddleName'], ENT_QUOTES);
            $LastName = htmlentities($_POST['LastName'], ENT_QUOTES);
            $ClientID = htmlentities($_POST['ClientID'], ENT_QUOTES);

            // check that FirstName and LastName are both not empty
            if ($FirstName == '' || $MiddleName == '' || $LastName == '' || $ClientID == '')
            {
                // if they are empty, show an error message and display the form
                $error = 'ERROR: Please fill in all required fields!';
                renderForm($FirstName, $MiddleName, $LastName, $ClientID, $error);
            }
            else
            {
                // insert the new record into the database
                if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT clients (FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, ClientID) VALUES (?, ?)"))
                {
                    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $FirstName, $MiddleName, $LastName, $ClientID);
                    $stmt->execute();
                    $stmt->close();
                }
                // show an error if the query has an error
                else
                {
                    echo "ERROR: Could not prepare SQL statement.";
                }

                // redirec the user
                header("Location: view.php");
            }

        }
        // if the form hasn't been submitted yet, show the form
        else
        {
            renderForm();
        }
    }

    // close the mysqli connection
    $mysqli->close();
?>
```

Comment: My first word of advice is use the `mysqli_` series of methods instead of `mysql_` which has been deprecated in favor of the **i**mproved series.

Comment: I've rolled your question back to it's original state. If you're going to update it with more information _please_ do not change the contents that are there, only add to it. In the future when someone visits this page the answers won't make sense because you changed the question.

Answer (score 1):

First, you're not escaping your `value` attributes. That's probably the cause of your `<td` that you're seeing.

You've got:

```
echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=MiddleName value=" . $record['MiddleName'] . " </td>";
```

**EDIT** To demonstrate, the output from this assuming there was no MiddleName (`""` should be: `<td><input type=text name=MiddleName value= </td>`, that doesn't look right. The output from below would be: `<td><input type="text" name="MiddleName" value=""></td>` now you can see that empty MiddleName value is `""` in the HTML - an empty string there as well.

And it should be:

```
echo "<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"MiddleName\" value=\"" . $record['MiddleName'] . "\"></td>";
```

That should resolve that issue. Notice that I've placed `\"` around your attributes. This is not PHP, this is HTML, all attribute values should be enclosed in quotes (I could have used single quotes (`'`) but I prefer double quotes).

The second problem is also a simple solution but again, not PHP - this is a SQL question.

A search is basically where X is like Y. There is actually an operator for this in SQL, `LIKE`. Now, this example isn't necessarily the most efficient means of searching, but it's definitely useful.

So you're getting the name from the request.

```
$name = $_REQUEST["query"];

// NEVER DO THE FOLLOWING, NOT EVER. Never trust input from a user, NEVER.
// Don't even think about putting input from the user in a query like this.
// If this input was: "'; DROP TABLE users; --" then you just lost your 
// user database.
// $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE FirstName LIKE '%" . $name . "%';";

// Do this instead (with mysqli, not mysql)
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE FirstName LIKE '%" . mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $name) . "%';";

// Now search
$results = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

// Do something with results.
```

And of course, finally - pagination. You want to paginate. That's a good idea. Here's a simple way to do that. First things first, you'll want to pass a piece of query data along with your request, like `?page=1` on the end of your URLs. This is important.

```
const PER_PAGE = 30;

if (array_key_exists($_REQUEST, "page")) {
  $page = intval($_REQUEST["page"]);
} else {
  $page = 1;
}

$offset = PER_PAGE * ($page - 1);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users LIMIT " . $offset . ", " . PER_PAGE . ";";
$res = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

// Render your page links:

// leave php, no need to echo every line of HTML.
// Fetch the count of total users with:
// SELECT COUNT(id) FROM users; -- replace id with your primary key field
// and then get your number of pages by '$count / PER_PAGE'
?>

<?php if ($pageCount > 1) { ?>
  <div class="pagination">
    <?php if ($page > 1) { ?>
      <a href="/users?page=<?php echo ($page - 1); ?>">Previous</a>
    <?php } else { ?>
      <span>Previous</span>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php for ($i = 1; i < $pageCount; $i++) {
      if ($page === $i) { ?>
        <span class="current-page"><?php echo $i; ?></span>
      <?php } else { ?>
        <a href="/users?page=<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></a>
      <?php }
    } ?>
    <?php if ($page < $pageCount) { ?>
      <a href="/users?page=<?php echo ($page + 1); ?>">Next</a>
    <?php } else { ?>
      <span>Next</span>
    <?php } ?>
  </div>
<?php } ?>
```

It is rather ugly with the embedded PHP, my apologies for that. There are other alternatives but I wouldn't want to push too much into one post for a newbie.

**EDIT**

Obviously you might want to make your pagination smarter. Like, if you have 10 pages you might not want to see: `Previous 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 Next` if you're onw page 7, you might just want to show: `Previous 5 6 7 8 9 Next` or some other alternative to keep your list from getting out of control. I didn't demonstrate this, I demonstrated the basic form of Pagination that you can start with and then you can try to modify that with to achieve your desired goals.

For further study I would like to give you some topics to research once you feel you've gotten a grasp on these and other basic tasks.

- Prepared statements - while the way I showed you (using `mysqli_real_escape_string()`) is safer than adding the string directly to the query, prepared statements are even safer than that.
- PDO - A seemingly logical next step up the chain of database access is PDO - basically building an ORM for you Database objects (and, I guess, also ORM).
- Different pagination techniques, not just of rendering the links. But try your hand with "infinite scrolling." this will require some knowledge of AJAX.
- AJAX - need to know some JavaScript and I'd recommend doing this, at first, without something like jQuery.
- Something like jQuery, building interactive applications.

From there, I hope you're already finding new things to learn that are referenced when trying to seek the above. This is all basic web development knowledge that would be good to have.

Comment: okay I feel very stupid atm. Where do I put this code into my page at?

Comment: Your search query, where would I place the code in my page

Comment: Ideally you'd have a page for handling search. And then it would go there. You already have some knowledge of querying, apply that to this new challenge. How did you get the current page working?

Comment: actually, I since you suggested I use msqli I scraped that whole page and went a completely different direction and I already have pagination working. I have a page for adding clients, one for viewing and one for deleting. I am going to bed soon, but I will try the search tomorrow. I am using this example now and modifying it for my needs. [Mysqli and php](http://www.killersites.com/community/index.php?/topic/3064-basic-php-system-view-edit-add-delete-records-with-mysqli/)

Answer (score 0):

For first part, you don't have quotes outputting correctly.

```
echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=MiddleName value=" . $record['MiddleName'] . " </td>";
```

should be

```
echo "<td>" . '<input type="text" name="MiddleName" value="' . $record['MiddleName'] . '"/> </td>';
```

or

```
echo "<td><input type='text' name='MiddleName' value='{$record['MiddleName']}'></td>";
```

You can use variables inside double quotes in PHP.  You can access array inside if you surround with curly braces, you can also access objects.  I feel it is more readable but some like to concatinate.

For second par, you can use GET variables in url, such as index.php?page=1&per_page=10

For searching

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM clients WHERE FirstName = '$firstName'";
// or
$query = "SELECT * FROM clients WHERE FirstName LIKE '%$firstName%'";
```

Also, the mysql driver is being removed in the next version of PHP, as it has been deprecated for a while, mysqli should be used instead.

Comment: There is error in: `echo "<td><input type="text" name="MiddleName" value="{$record['MiddleName']}"></td>";`

Answer (score 0):

As Xeridea wrote check your html. And if you need to display 10 results change your sql request to

> `$sql = "SELECT * FROM clients LIMIT 10";`

or if you need clienst 10 - 20

> `$sql = "SELECT * FROM clients LIMIT 10,10";`

first `10` - from,
 second how many

if you need select clients the name is John

> `$sql = "SELECT * FROM clients WHERE name = 'John';`

Create dinamicly links depends on pages(you can set it in url `$_GET` request) and use `LIMIT` to flip pages. Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

You just have to add below code before select query and use my select query.

> $SearchString = ''; if(isset($_POST['searchtext']) &&
>   $_POST['searchtext']!=''){    $searchtext = $_POST['searchtext'];
>   $SearchString = " WHERE FirstName LIKE "'.$searchtext.' ";
>   mysql_query($AddQuery, $con); };
>
> $sql = "SELECT * FROM clients".$SearchString;

Comment: I add the code you mentioned and it gave me an error on line 30 I will edit the original post with the new code

Comment: Don't search this way, this is highly prone to attack. I urge you to check my answer for a better way to handle searching.

Comment: That's even worse. If he's a beginner the. It's the worst time to introduce dangerous code. At least without explicitly pointing out that it's dangerous and why. I too demoed this method, but with a disclaimer.

Comment: next time take care of it